# refactoring of simple code in Yii2 (if-else)

Tags: yii2, refactoring

i was doing some refactoring of code on project in Yii2 framework.

I'm just asking if this can be written nicer, with less repetition (i try to follow DRY whenever i can). Any literature recommendation about this kind of topic is more than welcome, sorry for bad English.

```
$exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;

    if ($exception !== null) {
        if (isset($exception->statusCode)) {
            if ($exception->statusCode == 500) {
                return $this->render('error-500', ['exception' => $exception]);
            } elseif ($exception->statusCode == 404) {
                return $this->render('error-404', ['exception' => $exception]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('error', ['exception' => $exception]);
            }
        } elseif (isset($exception->code)) {
            if ($exception->code == 500) {
                return $this->render('error-500', ['exception' => $exception]);
            } elseif ($exception->code == 404) {
                return $this->render('error-404', ['exception' => $exception]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('error', ['exception' => $exception]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $exception = new \yii\web\HttpException(500);
        return $this->render('error-500', ['exception' => $exception]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so if you like

```
    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;

    if ($exception !== null) {
        if (isset($exception->statusCode){
            return $this-render('error-' . $exception->statusCode , ['exception' => $exception] );
        } else if (isset($exception->code)) {
            return $this-render('error-' . $exception->code , ['exception' => $exception] )
        } else {
        $exception = new \yii\web\HttpException(500);
        return $this->render('error-500', ['exception' => $exception]);
        }
    }
```

or so if like more compact

```
    if ($exception !== null) {
        if (isset($exception->statusCode,  $exception->code){
            return $this-render('error-' . ($exception->statusCode) ? $exception->statusCode : $exception->code , ['exception' => $exception] );
        } else {
        $exception = new \yii\web\HttpException(500);
        return $this->render('error-500', ['exception' => $exception]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way

```
     if ($exception !== null) {

        $exceptionCode = isset($exception->statusCode)?$exception->statusCode:
                ( isset($exception->code)?$exception->code:null );

        if($exceptionCode){
            $viewFile = ($exceptionCode == 500)?'error-500':
                    ( ($exceptionCode == 404)?'error-404':'error');

            return $this->render($viewFile, ['exception' => $exception]);

        } else {
            // you need to something here
        }

    }
```